# UIDynamicAnimator interfering with addTarget and beginTouches?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I wish I had more reputation so I could attach a screenshot of what I'm working on but you can see an example in the second link down below.

Basically there is a middle button in the tab bar which brings out option buttons (apple images in this case).

These apple icons are animated to their positions using UIDynamicAnimator and UIAttachmentBehavior.

Here is the code which adds the option buttons

```
func showOptions() {
    var numberOfItems = self.delegate.brOptionsButtonNumberOfItems(self)
    //NSAssert(numberOfItems > 0 , "number of items should be more than 0")
    var angle = 0.0
    var radius:Int = 20 * numberOfItems
    angle = (180.0 / Double(numberOfItems))

    // convert to radians
    angle = angle/180.0 * M_PI
    for(var i = 0; i<numberOfItems; i++) {
        var csCalc = Float((angle * Double(i)) + (angle/2))
        var buttonX = Float(radius) * cosf(csCalc)
        var buttonY = Float(radius) * sinf(csCalc)
        var wut = (angle * Double(i)) + (angle/2)
        var brOptionItem = self.createButtonItemAtIndex(i)
        var mypoint = self.tabBar.convertPoint(self.center, fromView:self.superview)

        var x = mypoint.x + CGFloat(buttonX)
        var y = self.frame.origin.y - CGFloat(buttonY)
        var buttonPoint = CGPointMake(x, y)

        //println("Button Point of Button Item x:\(x) y: \(y)")

        brOptionItem.layer.anchorPoint = self.layer.anchorPoint
        brOptionItem.center = mypoint

        var attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item:brOptionItem, attachedToAnchor:buttonPoint)
        attachment.damping = self.damping
        attachment.frequency = self.frequency
        attachment.length = 1

        // set the attachment for dragging behavior
        brOptionItem.attachment = attachment
        self.dynamicItem!.addItem(brOptionItem)
        //if(self.delegate.respondsToSelector("willDisplayButtonItem")) { //Fix me
            //self.delegate.brOptionsButton(self, willDisplayButtonItem:brOptionItem)

        //}

        self.tabBar.insertSubview(brOptionItem, belowSubview: self.tabBar)
        self.dynamicsAnimator!.addBehavior(attachment)
        self.items.addObject(brOptionItem)
    }
}

func createButtonItemAtIndex(indexz:NSInteger) -> BROptionsItem {
    println("Create button item at index")
    var brOptionItem = BROptionsItem(initWithIndex:indexz)
    brOptionItem.addTarget(self, action:"buttonItemPressed:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    brOptionItem.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.None
        var image = self.delegate.brOptionsButton(self, imageForItemAtIndex:indexz)

        //if((image) != nil) {
            brOptionItem.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        //}
            /*

        var buttonTitle = self.delegate.brOptionsButton(self, titleForItemAtIndex:indexz)

        if(buttonTitle.utf16Count > 0) {

            brOptionItem.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState:UIControlState.Normal)

        }
        */
    return brOptionItem;
}
```

In showOptions the animator is assigned an attachment behavior for a brOptionItem that was just created when createButtomItemAtIndex was called.

In createButtonItemAtIndex, the brOptionItem is created and a target was added to execute a function when the button was tapped.

The option buttons work without the animation. I can click them and the target function is executed.

However, when the animation is added and the option buttons are placed where they are, nothing happens when the buttons are tapped.

I am extremely stuck on this. I have no idea why the animation stops the tapping actions. The buttons are supposed to be draggable as well.

Here is my source code. The code I reference can be see in the BROptiosnButton file.

https://github.com/WobbleDev/BROptionsSwift

Here is the reference code I used

https://github.com/BasheerSience/BROptionsButton

Thanks!